# paginating using angularfire2

Tags: pagination, angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

suppose I have a data structure in firebase real time database like

```
{ "donors" : 
      "uid1" : { "name" : "x", "bloodGroup" : "A+", "location" : "some Place"},
      "uid2" : { "name" : "y", "bloodGroup" : "A-", "location" : "some place"},
      ...
      ...
}
```

now if I have millions of donor records like this. how could I filter them based on `bloodGroup`  `location` and fetching say `100` records from server at a time using angularfire2.

Comment: The topic of pagination with Firebase has been discussed a lot of times already. Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this page which was really helpful to me when using queries to query my firebase data:

https://howtofirebase.com/collection-queries-with-firebase-b95a0193745d

A very simple example would be along the lines of:

```
this.donorsData = af.database.list('/donors', {
              query: {
                orderByChild: 'bloodGroup',
                equalTo: 'A+',
              }
            });
```

Not entirely sure how to fetch 100 records, then another 100, I am using datatables in my app, which fetches all my data and using the datatables for pagination.